# How to run a Java project without build file

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I have a Java project in NetBeans.

While changing my laptop, I lost its build file. How do I run that project? How can I make the build file?

Answer (score 0):

`cd src`(source folder)

```
javac package_name/main_file.java

java package_name.main_file
```

**Note : Before using `java` and `javac` command make sure the `path` variable is already set and all the required dependencies are available in path.**

[How to set path in java](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java)

Comment: How do you know this will build the OP's project. What about classpaths, dependencies, etc.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMarkidis, good point to catch. I have updated the question.